# how to pass value to pointer member of a structure

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, structure

I have defined nested structure containing pointer member in the inner structure. how to pass value to the  pointer member which is array of 6 elements for example. It is compiling but not working.

how to pass value to this pointer?

```
        typedef struct
    {
        int Nx;
        int Nu;
        float *x_initial;
    }typeparam;

    typedef struct
    {
        typeparam *param;
    }typeram;

    int main()
    {

        float x0[6]={-2.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
        typeram *ram, ram1;
        ram= &ram1;

       for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
           ram->param->x_initial[i] = x0[i];
          }

         for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
                printf("%1.6f\n",ram->param->x_initial[i] );
         }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Please read [ask]

Comment: What is the use of `ram`? Why not use `ram1` directly?

Comment: And think about where the pointers in the structures (like e.g. `ram1.param`) are pointing. Are you really sure you want to use pointers everywhere?

Comment: Where is `ram->param` pointing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that within the structure

```
typedef struct
{
    typeparam *param;
}typeram;
```

there is defined a data member of a pointer type

```
    typeparam *param;
```

and it is not initialized and has indeterminate value. You have to initialize the data member for example dynamically allocating memory for an object of the type typeparam and assigning the address of the allocated memory to this data member.

For example

```
    #include <stdlib.h>

    //...

    typeram *ram, ram1;
    ram= &ram1;

    ram1.param = malloc( sizeof( typeparam ) );
```

And then do not gorget to free the allocated memory after at the end of the progran.

```
   free( ram1.param );
```

or

```
   free( ram->param );
```

Otherwise the program has undefined behavior due to using this data member with the indeterminate value.

Comment: how to initialise a data member without dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @pva18 The same way as you initialized the pointer ram. That is by defining an object of the type typeparam and setting the data member with the address of the object.

Answer (score 0):

let me simplify my code here :

```
 typedef struct
{
    int Nx;
    int Nu;
    float *x_initial;
}typeparam;

int main()
{

    float x0[6]={-2.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    //float x;
    typeparam *ram, ram1;
    ram= &ram1;
    ram->x_initial = &x0;
   for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
       ram->x_initial[i] = x0[i];
      }

     for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
            printf("%1.6f\n",ram->x_initial[i] );
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Now its just one structure. Also I have initialised both pointers - ram as well as x_initial - I want to assign the values of x0 to x_initial. The above code gives error - cant convert from float* to float - incompatible pointer types